# C, Large pointer array allocation (linux 64 bit)

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, memory, allocation

Im allocating 25,000,000,000 units of these :

```
struct test
{
 public:
 test();
 void insert(unsigned int var1, unsigned int var2, unsigned long var3);
      bool isEmpty() const;
      unsigned char * data;
};


test::test()
{
data = NULL;
}

bool test::isEmpty() const
{
  return (data == NULL);
}


unsigned long index = 25000000000;
```

like this :

```
test *something = new (nothrow) test[index];
    if (!something)
     {
     cout << "Error allocating memory for [something]" << endl;
     return ;
    }
    cout << "DONE !" << endl;
```

then i even `made sure` its `data` initialized to NULL.

```
unsigned long j=0;
        while (j<index) 
        {
          something[j].data = NULL;
          j++;
        }
```

And its all good, except when i iterate through the something[], like this :

```
test *chk;
unsigned long empty = 0;
unsigned long not_empty = 0;
unsigned long i=0;
for (i=0; i< index; i++ )
{ 
    chk = &something[i];
    if (!chk->isEmpty())
     {
    not_empty++;
    } else
    empty++;
}


cout << "Empty [" << empty << "]" << endl;
cout << "Not Empty [" << not_empty << "]" << endl;
cout << "Total [" << empty + not_empty << "]" << endl;
```

(LAST UPDATE)

It turned out to be hardware problem - memory. Some of sticks were not working properly together with others. Thanks everyone for suggestions and too bad hardware path isnt in answers o/

(UPDATE)

I get constant number of initialized elements that are not NULL (not_empty). Still have no idea why. 
Of course, empty + not_empty = index.

If i comment out `data = NULL;` in constructor function, i get proper empty/not_empty numbers if i loop through array right after allocating it. but still, after forcing pointers to NULL, i get same constant not_empty value, after looping through array again.

I also had this reworked to plain pointers, using malloc(), and it made no difference, except that it was first the time i noticed pointers to be correct (empty) until i set them.

I did some tests with smaller [index] value (5,500,000,000), and i could not replicate the behavior.

Im using google`s ltcmalloc and allocated memory size suggests, it is using correct [index] size;

Comment: Updated tag from c to c++.

Comment: I have tried this with a much smaller number of elements (because I have only 16GB of RAM), and without `ltcmalloc`. It works correctly. I don't see why `ltcmalloc` would cause a problem - it's just a different memory allocator, it shouldn't affect the way objects are initialized...

Comment: I trust you're aware that you've allocated 100 GB space for the pointers; if you need to allocate something different for each of those to point at, you'll need at least twice that much memory (since allocations of even single characters normally use at least 16 bytes per allocation on a 64-bit machine).  That's a lot of main memory.  It isn't directly a factor in your problem, but if you don't have a lot of main memory, your code is going to be extremely slow.

Comment: not 100 GB, but 200GB. in 64 bit environment pointers take 8 bytes. these pointers are then used on similarly sized data blob, representing a huge array of short linked lists. sorted data structure. problem, however, is, im getting faulty/wrong/whatever initialized pointers to begin with. and im not sure what is my next step.

Comment: You might have a hardware problem.

Comment: bad news :) thanks for input. any other ideas ? because, if i decrease [index] size considerably ... i havent done that actually because there was no need to verify initialized pointers. lets just say, ive been allocating and using even bigger data blob on same hardware for some time, and it was fine. however, ill play with [index] size and report here later.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 25000000000, write 25000000000ul. I have suspect your number becomes a 32-bit integer, thus the j < 25000000000 is always true as int(25000000000) = -769803776.

Comment: [total] is always showing correctly. my concern is about [not_empty] being greater than 0; at that point i added useless NULLifing loop to force data pointers to NULL.

Comment: i have to admit, RAM clock frequency changes correlates with [not_empty] value. I would like to focus on software as long as i can. So, can i use a different allocation approach ?